# Online tool to visualize a curve of given curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, visualization

For my differential geometry class it would be superuseful to have a tool to which I feed a curvature formula and that spits out a representation of a planar curve with such curvature.

For example, if I feed it $\kappa(s) = \frac{1}{r}$ it should paint me a circumference.

Know anything already out there?

Bonus points if it gives me an explicit formula whenever it can be computed in closed form.

Extra bonus points if it can also be fed a torsion to work with 3D curves.

Comment: If you have access to Mathematica, I wrote various programs for my differential geometry students. In particular, I wrote a short [Mathematica primer](https://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/4250_Mathematica_Primer.nb) which has in it code for drawing a space curve, given curvature and torsion functions.